# How can i automate site access HBase

Tags: automated-testing

i have a web site deals with HBase instead of oracle and HBase Dosen't have any interface to Query on it such as Oracle, So i want a tool to automate this site

Comment: What exactly do you want to automate?  The web site, or directly querying HBase?  Can you give more specific examples of how the site works and what scenario you want to automate?  HBase provides both a Java API as well as a REST API to query data if you need to query it in automation.

Comment: @Sam Woods  Example we have a lot of tables in Hbase and access these tables on site and i want to connect this data by any automation tool example "Jmeter tool" we can make connection on oracle and do performance test but now we have already changed from oracle to hbase and hbase dont have interface to deal with it and i can't do any query on it only by exact key and in our tables i have keys and want to filter by partial key and i can't do this so, i want to find any tool to automate "jsp site + Hbase "

Comment: And if you have any knowledge about automate the website (java api) or  directly querying HBase please help me and give me any inforamtion you have it in this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HBase Java API to query hbase, here is some documentation on how that works:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.2/bk_system-admin-guide/content/ch_ha-HBase-query-API.html

You can also google "query HBASE with Java API" and you find a bunch of info there on how to do this.